# Rails custom validation messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to set form validation with cyrillic alphabet but I get

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
```

Here is the code that I use

```
  validates_presence_of :user, :message => "кирилица"
```

What is wrong here ?

Comment: what is the error message generated in log file?

Comment: This should work with ruby 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to tell ruby that your source file is in utf-8

Ruby 1.9 assumes your source files are US-ASCII encoded unless you provide an

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

comment at the beginning of your source file

PS : I would suggest you to use i18n to store your validation messages. You can find info about the mechanism [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models), it will allow you to either change default messages or specific messages for a model.

Comment: That was the problem. But is there more elegant solution. I don't want to put this line at every file of project where utf8 encoding is used

Comment: I added a PS about a more elegant solution